# Clicking noise when cranks rotate

Tags: repair, fixed-gear, noise, mechanical

I've got an old `86 Raleigh fixed gear bicycle that is making a loud clicking noise when the cranks rotates. It seems to have just started doing this today. I'm looking for someone who, maybe has experienced this type of noise with a bike before, that can possibly point me in the right direction to fixing it.

Both bolts on each side are stripped so I'm not sure how I'd get it apart to see if it could be the bottom bracket, if you have any ideas on how to do that, that's appreciated too.

The only thing that I can think of that could possibly be a variable in this is yesterday I sprayed some pb blaster down my seat post and into a little hole in the frame to get my extremely stuck seat to come loose.

Anyway...here's a video of the noise:

Comment: There are a half-dozen possible causes, but the somewhat irregular nature of the sound suggests it has something to do with the chain or chainrings.  First check that the chainring bolts are tight.  Oh, and to eliminate several other possibilities give each crank arm a good shake, looking for any looseness at the crank arm to shaft connection or between the crank shaft and the bearings.  And maybe you can send a small mouse down there to get the PB out!

Comment: chainring bolts are very tight, i took the chain off and its still making the noise, no looseness in the crank arms

Comment: (I'll note that this doesn't appear to be a "fixed gear" bike, since I see two chainrings.  And your problem may be somehow connected to the fact that the bike was somewhat clumsily painted at some time in the past.  Paint may have gotten into the bearings.)

Comment: When you were working on the seatpost you may have gotten some bits of debris into the bearings.

Comment: Probably you're going to have to take the crank arms off and re-pack the crank bearings.  I'm not sure what you mean by "the bolts on both sides are stripped", as all I see is the plastic cover over the bolt head, and it would be pretty hard to strip the crank bolts so long as you used the right size wrench.  Of course, once you get the bolts out you will still need a crank puller to get the crank arms off, so best talk to a friend who has some bike tools.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I see no front mech - I bet its a conversion and they simply haven't bothered taking the inner chainring off.  May not even know its removable, or maybe the chainring bolts are too long for a single ring setup.

Comment: Does it make the same noises if you pedal forward too?

Comment: @Criggie - It's confusing, since the smaller ring seems to show some wear after it was painted.

Comment: @Criggie yea, its fixed. but anywho it does make the noise no matter which way its pedaling

Comment: Why the heck has this got a downvote? Question is clear and a video is included that clearly demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus thats what I was wondering ha!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like the bottom bracket bearings to me.

It could be the chain, but you can eliminate that by loosening the rear wheel and slipping the chain off the chainring.

It's not chainring bolts as these only creak under load. It's not the bottom bracket cups for the same reason.

You appear to have a loose ball bearing bottom bracket with an axle with square tapers that the cranks fit onto. I linked a video below that shows how to service this type of bearings. When you say 'Both bolts on each side are stripped' I think you mean the end-caps. You should be able to get those off by jamming something that will engage with the rounded off hex hole. I'd try a large screwdriver with a tapered head.

Comment: But, as I indicated earlier, getting the thing apart requires some specialized tools and at least modest mechanic's skills.